# chkrootkit checking sniffer's log takes ages

Tags: chkrootkit

On my server chkrootkit hangs on

```
Searching for sniffer's logs, it may take a while...
```

After half an hour, I stopped this, so how can I find out what `chkrootkit` is trying to achieve in this step?

I looked at the code and it seems this is the part that takes so long:

```
files=`${find} ${ROOTDIR}dev ${ROOTDIR}tmp ${ROOTDIR}lib ${ROOTDIR}etc ${ROOTDIR}var \
   ${findargs} \( -name "tcp.log" -o -name ".linux-sniff" -o -name "sniff-l0g" -o -name "core_" \) \
   2>/dev/null`
```

chkrootkit tries to find sniffer-logs in these places:

```
find /dev /tmp /lib /etc /var ( -name tcp.log -o -name .linux-sniff -o -name sniff-l0g -o -name core_ )
```

which could be huge, cause on my server I backup into `/var/backups/rsnapshot/` which would be inside `/var`

What can I do to speedup `chkrootkit`?

Can I blacklist `/var/backup` or change that `find` code line so it doesn't search in that folder?

Comment: Make /var/backups a separate partition, then unmount it when you run chkrootkit?

Comment: feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chkrootkit/+bug/1397548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust find to your likings with the `prune` option. something like this:

```
find /var -type d -path /var/backups -prune -o -print
```

*edit: simpler syntax,absolut path*

Comment: But then I would have to re-patch this after each apt-get update of chkrootkit